# jquery select first child by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the first child of clicked element and my click listener must be tied to the class "test". How can I do this?

```
<span class="test">click<input type="text" value="1"></span>
<span class="test">click<input type="text" value="2"></span>
<span class="test">click<input type="text" value="3"></span>
<span class="test">click<input type="text" value="4"></span>
```

I'm trying this but it's always returning `1`.

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    $test = $(".test").children("input[type='text']:first").val();
    alert($test);
});
```

Here is jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/6zudq9wy/

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing all `test` class elements within the click function, so jQuery will pick the first and output its' first children. Instead, reference `this`:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    $test = $(this).children("input[type='text']:first").val();
    alert($test);
});
```

Comment: Small tip: When you using jQUery, **$** sign in variable name is generally used for jQuery object, not it's value or any other type.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this:

```js
$(".test").click(function(){
    alert ($(this).children().eq(0).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">click<input type="text" value="1"></span>
    <span class="test">click<input type="text" value="2"></span>
    <span class="test">click<input type="text" value="3"></span>
    <span class="test">click<input type="text" value="4"></span>
```